# Elliptic PDE- solution in weak sense

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives, elliptic-equations

I looking for some literature, where I can find strategy how to solve elliptic PDE in weak sense - define notion of weak solution. Can anyone recommend me something ? Or some links to solved examples. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you [a book](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-19-r). Specifically, Part II.

Comment: @Frederico I konow about this book, but I lookinf for some book with solved example, because I have problem to formulate problem weakly for elliptic PDE.